# How to install Ubuntu on ARM64 chromebook with MediaTek mt8183?

Tags: ubuntu-mate, chromebook, arm64

I have a Chromebook that uses MediaTek mt8183.

This device has no UEFI or Legacy Boot. only altfw.

Chrome OS is so useless. The specs are what I was needing, but it's almost impossible to do anything that I need to do on it. I absolutely despise it and would exchange it, but not only do I live in a small area, it's 2/3 years old. If anybody, anybody at all could help me out with this I would be greatly thankful to you. Chrome OS is basically useless on an ARM64 CPU.

How to install Ubuntu (preferably Ubuntu MATE) on it?

Comment: There are some github projects for installing GNU/Linux on Arm chromebooks. What is your chromebook model?

Comment: See https://github.com/hexdump0815/linux-mainline-on-arm-chromebooks for details

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi IdeaPad 3. These are also supposedly sold as Windows devices but (per my knowledge) cost way more. No external scripts have been found to work per my own research. Crouton Is NOT what I am looking for. Mr. Chromebox does not support ARM64 and all other scripts (so far) do nothing.    I see it has been listed on your github page as Fennel14. I will see what I can do and if you wish to keep in contact for further info feel free to ask for my email.

Comment: Your chromebook seems to be supported by this GitHub project. If you have any questions about how to install, feel free to open a GitHub issue. https://github.com/hexdump0815/imagebuilder/issues

Comment: The Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy) image for booting is available [here](https://github.com/hexdump0815/imagebuilder/releases/tag/230218-01), and instructions for how to boot the image is available [here](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Chrome_OS_devices#Preparation)

Comment: Is there a method to do a permanent install of this onto the Chromebook? I'd like to be able to just get rid of ChromeOS. Once removed Google is incapable of saying anything about the device because they do not own it.

Comment: For permanent install, you will have to write the image to eMMC described here https://github.com/hexdump0815/imagebuilder/blob/main/doc/install-to-emmc-on-arm-chromebooks.md Only do that if you can successfully use the image from your SD card, and if all the hardware work satisfactorily, as this method is irreversible, and also may brick your device if the commands contain typing errors.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it asked for updates. Upon updating & rebooting it stopped working. I had already removed chromeOS and I am now stuck with an unbootable SD card. What to do now?

Comment: You can again flash the sd card in another computer. I would advice you not to apply kernel updates.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi provided dd method doesn't work. It also makes the SD & hard drive unbootable.

Comment: How did you make it work previously (you said it stopped working after an update)

Comment: Extracted the .img, renamed to .bin and used chrome recovery tool to write it.

Comment: Try writing it with [Balena Etcher](https://etcher.balena.io/) instead of DD (enaming to .bin is probably unnecessary). In the extreme case, use Chrome recovery tool in a Windows computer. It is available as an addon for the Google Chrome Browser, in the Chrome Web Store

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi is there any known method to make this work and allow kernel updates? If so, please let me know where to go to do so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I really don't know. I don't have an ARM chromebook to test. I shared with you what I found with a google search

Comment: By the way, not updating the kernel does not make the computer significantly unsafe.

Comment: I noticed. It would just run better if it were possible to update the kernel.

Comment: BTW, how is the performance? And, which kernel is this?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi it's actually much better than this other project I tried. It's called pmOS and the performance was TERRIBLE. I'm switching back to this on the Jammy kernel.

Comment: Another suggestion: after you have installed ubuntu and installed all the software you need, clone the sdcard to another card for backup (and test whether the backup works). Then, even if something goes wrong in an update, you can immediately start using the other card

Comment: Now that you have installed ubuntu, can you compile your own answer below?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no, not quite. I still need to figure out how to make the singular TouchPad work as an actual TouchPad and not a 2 button mousepad